# Error: spawn Rscript ENOENT when executing r-script in Node.js

Tags: r, node.js

I am trying to run with Node.js a little R script(the example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-script) but I am always having the next error when I execute `node index.js`:

```
events.js:174
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^

Error: spawn Rscript ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

How can it be fixed? I also tried with js-call-r but I am having the same issue.
Thank you.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. You are able to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I couldn't. I had to use plumber package to be able to run R scripts.

Comment: Tysm.. Can You share your reference site url :-) It would be great help

Comment: Yes, here you have: [link](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber) It creates an API and you can have access from NodeJS with requests.